# I can't use require in my html script, can anyone answer why?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Whenever I try to use the require function in my html, i get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

```
<script>
            var fs = require('fs');
</script>
```

This code gives me an error.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please give us the **Javascript** or the code for this, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Use `import()` instead, this is straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, you can't do it in vanilla JS. Require is a special function, that you gonna use from library or enviroment(like nodejs), so as ypu don't have function with that name - browser throw you an err "require is not defined", he just don't see function with this name )

I don't know what you r going to require or what u r worked with, so can't tell u more. You should add more info.

Comment: thanks a lot! i was needing it as i was making a login page, where all the users are stored in a .json file, so to access the json, i needed to use the require function

Answer (score 0):

`require()` isn't a part of vanilla JavaScript, you presumably need NodeJS to use it.